# controling the tabs of the tabs bar in gwt

Tags: gwt, user-interface, width, widget, tabpanel

sorry for stupid question i am new to UI in general and gwt specifically

1. how can i control the tabs width
   when using tabs panel in gwt? how
2. how can i know what css attributes
   each widget has? i would like to
   control the tabs color (selected and
   not selected) and remove the tabs frame

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are new to UI in general, maybe you don't know [Firebug]. It is a Firefox plugin that allows you (among other things) to inspect every element in a page and know how the styles are beeing applied and even change them in real-time. It is **vital** for GWT development.

Besides that, in order to control each tab style separatelly, I think you will need to insert Labels on the tabs, using `TabBar.addTab(Widget widget)`, and set their styles.

Comment: so this is how people know which gwt control adds certain html element?

another question: how can i know which css attributes can be set in for each gwt widget?
meaning how can know what i can put in .gwt-DecoratedTabBar{}??


thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: I don't think this is documented anywhere. Usually basic styles like colors and fonts will work fine. Most elements are Divs or Tables. More "structural" attributes, like width and padding can be more complicated. I think that, unless you have a designer creating the htmls for you, it is better to define the layout in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DecoratedTabBar.html) for DecoratedTabBar lists style names you can use for both the selected and unselected tabs.

```
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar { the tab bar itself }
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .gwt-TabBarFirst { the left edge of the bar }
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .gwt-TabBarRest { the right edge of the bar }
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .gwt-TabBarItem { unselected tabs }
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .gwt-TabBarItem-wrapper { table cell around tab }
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .gwt-TabBarItem-selected { additional style for selected tabs }
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .gwt-TabBarItem-wrapper-selected { table cell around selected tab }
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .tabTopLeft { top left corner of the tab}
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .tabTopLeftInner { the inner element of the cell}
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .tabTopCenter { top center of the tab}
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .tabTopCenterInner { the inner element of the cell}
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .tabTopRight { top right corner of the tab}
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .tabTopRightInner { the inner element of the cell}
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .tabMiddleLeft { left side of the tab }
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .tabMiddleLeftInner { the inner element of the cell}
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .tabMiddleCenter { center of the tab, where the tab text or widget resides }
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .tabMiddleCenterInner { the inner element of the cell}
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .tabMiddleRight { right side of the tab }
* .gwt-DecoratedTabBar .tabMiddleRightInner { the inner element of the cell}
```